# Saving Core Data in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I work with Core Data, all data is added to AddTodoView(), all this data is placed in contentView(), but the problem is. that when I remove this application from multitasking, the "card" with the data disappears

Here I place data from Core Data:
ContentView()

```
VStack{
    //MARK: - CARD
    ForEach(self.manyTasksTodo, id: \.self) { (todoDB: TodoDB) in
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
            
            ZStack{
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        deleteTodo(todoDB: todoDB)
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                        .padding(.bottom,30)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                })
                
                Divider()
                
                Text(todoDB.attribute ?? "Unknown attribute")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                //.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            Text(todoDB.name ?? "Unknown task")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.bottom)
            
            
            Text(todoDB.date ?? Date(), style: .date)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.callout)
            
            
            HStack{
                //...
                Spacer()
                
            }
            
        }//VStack
        .padding()
        .background(Color(todoDB.color ?? ""))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding()
        
    }//: FOREACH
    
    Spacer()
    
}
```

This is where the addition to Core Data itself takes place:
AddTodoView()

```
//MARK: - BUTTON ADD TODO
Button(action: {
    if self.name != "" && self.attribute != ""{
        let todoDB = TodoDB(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        todoDB.name = self.name 
        todoDB.attribute = self.attribute
        todoDB.date = self.date
        todoDB.color = self.color
        
        do{
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    } else{
        self.errorShow = true
        self.errorTitle = NSLocalizedString("The task was not added", comment: "")
        self.errorMessage = NSLocalizedString("Enter a task or select an attribute" , comment: "")
    }
},
       label: {
    Text("Add")
        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold, design: .default))
})
```

Comment: It looks to me like you never call save() on your managedObjectContext

Comment: I wrote in the properties `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext`
If this is not entirely true, I will be glad if you tell me the correct spelling

Comment: That is not what I said, you need to call the function `save()` to persist your data. `try self.managedObjectContext.save()`

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, that's what I was missing.